# How come data from different sources for dividends don't match?

Tags: stocks, dividends

This is regarding dividends for SPX

Data from [ycharts](https://ycharts.com/indicators/sp_500_dividends_per_share):

```
| Dec 2019  | 15.21  |
| Sep 2019  | 14.80  |
| Jun 2019  | 14.24  |
| Mar 2019  | 13.98  |
```

This is regarding dividends for SPX

Data from [multpl](https://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-dividend/table/by-month)

```
| Dec 2019  | 58.63  |
| Sep 2019  | 57.65  |
| Jun 2019  | 56.63  |
| Mar 2019  | 55.90  |
```

It looks like the numbers were aggregated in someway to represent an annual dividend instead of a quarterly one. I am struggling to find the exact formula of the calculation in the reasoning behind this transformation of the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

From multpl:

> 12-month real dividend per share — **inflation adjusted** February, 2020 dollars.

I think you'll find the reason there. To make it easier to see, I highlighted it in bold.

(Also, as you already noted, it appears the multpl figures are annualized, not per-quarter dividends.)

Comment: I will admit that I am sometimes pretty ignorant of the world around me. However, I feel like the it did not take $58 in Feb 2020 to purchase the same things that it took $15 to purchase in Dec 2019...

Comment: It looks like a 12-month sliding window